# NDSolve not recognizing symbolic derivative as a function

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a nonlinear first order initial value problem $\{x'[t]= f[x,t],\ x[t_0]=x_0 \}$ using NDSolve. The function $f[x,t]$ is complicated, as is the computation of the initial x-value. The code computes these values accurately, but when I go to solve the IVP I get the error message:

```
NDSolve::ndode: The equations {True,0==SolSpeed[xsol[tsol]/tsol,0.25,1,2]} are not differential equations or initial conditions in the dependent variables {xsol}.
```

I've read lots of help files and tried restarting the kernel, but nothing seems to help. I'm sure my code isn't optimal, but I can't figure out why it won't run at all.

Any ideas?

Here is the full code, the `NDSolve` call is at the bottom inside a function called `SolPeakLeading`.

````
XiCrit[eta1_, eta2_] :=
 Module[{Whitham, m},
  Whitham[m_?NumberQ] = 
   4 (1 - m) EllipticK[m]/EllipticE[m] + 2 (1 + m);
  eta2^2*Whitham[eta1^2/eta2^2]
  ]

ComputeAlpha[xi_?NumericQ, eta1_?NumericQ, eta2_?NumericQ] :=
 
 Module[{xi$critical},
  xi$critical = XiCrit[eta1, eta2];
  If[xi >= xi$critical,
   eta2,
   Module[{Whitham, asq, ans, m},
    Whitham[m_?NumberQ] = 
     4 (1 - m) EllipticK[m]/EllipticE[m] + 2 (1 + m);
    asq = 
     asq /. FindRoot[
       xi == asq *
         Whitham[eta1^2/asq], {asq, ( 
          eta1 + (eta2 - 
              eta1)*(xi - 4 eta1^2)/(xi$critical - 4 eta1^2))^2},
       MaxIterations -> 150
       ];
    ans = Sqrt[asq];
    (* Now test if FindRoot gives a spurious complex answer *)
    
    If[Im [ans] != 0,
     (* If a nonzero real part switch to a bracketing method to \
compute alpha *)
     Clear[asq];
     Sqrt[
      asq /. FindRoot[
        xi == asq*Whitham[eta1^2/asq], {asq, eta1^2, eta2^2}, 
        Method -> "Secant"]],
     (* If false, return the original answer *)
     ans
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]

sol[xval_, tval_, eta1_, eta2_, kappa_, x0_, \[Sigma]_] :=
 
 If[xval < 4 eta1^2*tval,
  2 \[Sigma] kappa Sech[2 kappa (xval - x0 - 4 kappa^2 tval)], (* 
  If true, evaluate the zero background soliton *)
  (* If false, 
  the module computes the background and soliton solution in the \
elliptic regions *)
  Module[
   {
    xi, alpha, R, m1, eK, eK1, nome, \[Gamma]sq, Abel, \[CurlyPhi], 
    snSlow, dnSlow, cnSlow,
    Xi, TT, Omega, qBackground, Qminus, QminusPrime, w22sq, Y, X, 
    qsol
    },
   xi = xval/tval;
   alpha = ComputeAlpha[xi, eta1, eta2]; 
   R = -Sqrt[( kappa^2 - alpha^2) (kappa^2 - eta1^2)]; (* 
   R(k) evaluated at k=i\[Kappa] *)
   
   m1 = 4*alpha*eta1/(alpha + eta1)^2;
   eK = EllipticK[eta1^2/alpha^2];
   eK1 = EllipticK[m1];
   nome = Exp[-Pi EllipticK[1 - eta1^2/alpha^2]/(2 eK)] ;
   \[Gamma]sq = 
    Sqrt[(kappa - alpha)/(kappa - eta1) * (kappa + eta1)/(kappa + 
         alpha)]; (* \[Gamma]^2 evaluated at k=i\[Kappa] *)
   
   Abel = -InverseJacobiDC[kappa/alpha, eta1^2/alpha^2]/(4 eK); (* 
   Abel evaluated at k=i\[Kappa] > i \[Alpha]*)
   
   snSlow = JacobiSN[2 eK1 (Abel + 1/4), m1];
   cnSlow = JacobiCN[2 eK1 (Abel + 1/4), m1];
   dnSlow = JacobiDN[2 eK1 (Abel + 1/4), m1];
   (* 
   Everything before this is a function of the slow evolution \
variable \[Xi]. 
   Everything after depends on the fast (order one) evolution in xval \
and tval
   *)
   Omega[Xi_, TT_] = -Pi*alpha/eK*TT*(Xi - 2 (eta1^2 + alpha^2));
   (* Compared with notes \[CurlyPhi] (here) is really -
   I*\[CurlyPhi] + log(\[Chi])/
   2 (from notes)  *)
   \[CurlyPhi][Xi_, TT_] = 
    R *TT*(4 kappa - (1/
           kappa)*(EllipticPi[eta1^2/kappa^2, eta1^2/alpha^2]/
           eK)*(Xi - 2 (eta1^2 + alpha^2))) - kappa x0 + 
     Log[2 kappa]/2;
   qBackground[Xi_, 
     TT_] = (alpha + 
       eta1) JacobiDN[(alpha + eta1) TT (Xi - 2*(eta1^2 + alpha^2)) + 
       eK1, m1];
   Qminus[Xi_, 
     TT_] = ( \[Gamma]sq - 1)/(\[Gamma]sq + 1) * (alpha + 
        eta1)/(alpha - eta1)* dnSlow*
     JacobiDN[2 eK1 (Abel - 1/4 + Omega[xi, TT]/(2 Pi)), m1];
   QminusPrime[Xi_, 
     TT_] = ( 2 \[Gamma]sq)/(\[Gamma]sq + 1)^2 * (alpha + 
        eta1)*(kappa^2 + alpha *eta1)/R^2*dnSlow*
      JacobiDN[2 eK1 (Abel - 1/4 + Omega[Xi, TT]/(2 Pi)), m1]
     - 2 alpha *
      eta1/((alpha - eta1) R) *(\[Gamma]sq - 1)/(\[Gamma]sq + 1)*( 
       dnSlow*JacobiSN[2 eK1 (Abel - 1/4 + Omega[Xi, TT]/(2 Pi)), m1]*
         JacobiCN[2 eK1 (Abel - 1/4 + Omega[Xi, TT]/(2 Pi)), m1] + 
        snSlow*cnSlow*
         JacobiDN[2 eK1 (Abel - 1/4 + Omega[Xi, TT]/(2 Pi)), m1]
       );
   w22sq[Xi_, TT_] =  (\[Gamma]sq + 1)^2/(4 \[Gamma]sq) * 
     EllipticTheta[3, 0 , nome]^2*
     EllipticTheta[3, Pi (Abel + 1/4) + Omega[Xi, TT]/2 , 
        nome]^2/(EllipticTheta[3, Omega[Xi, TT]/2 , nome]^2*
        EllipticTheta[3, Pi (Abel + 1/4) , nome]^2);
   Y[Xi_, TT_] = (1 + Qminus[Xi, TT]^2)/(2 kappa);
   X[Xi_, TT_] = 
    1/(w22sq[Xi, TT]*\[Sigma]*Exp[2*\[CurlyPhi][Xi, TT]]) + 
     QminusPrime[Xi, TT];
   qsol[Xi_, 
     TT_] = (2 (1 - Qminus[Xi, TT]^2) X[Xi, TT] + 
       4 Qminus[Xi, TT]* Y[Xi, TT])/(X[Xi, TT]^2 + Y[Xi, TT]^2);
   
   qsol[xi, tval] + qBackground[xi, tval] 
   ]
  ]

SolSpeed[xi_?NumericQ, eta1_, eta2_, kappa_] :=
  Module[{alpha},
   alpha = ComputeAlpha[x$val/t$val, eta1, eta2];
   2 (eta1^2 + alpha^2) + 
    4 kappa^2 EllipticK[eta1^2/alpha^2] / 
      EllipticPi[eta1^2/kappa^2, eta1^2/alpha^2] 
   ];


SolPeakLeading[eta1_, eta2_, kappa_, x0_, sigma_, t$right_] :=
 
 Module[{t$initial, x$initial, t$left, ODEeqns, xmax},
  t$initial = (-x0 + 3)/(4 kappa^2 - 4 eta1^2);
  x$initial = 
   NArgMax[sol[xmax, t$initial, eta1, eta2, kappa, x0, sigma], xmax];
  t$left = -x0/(4 kappa^2 - 4 eta1^2) + .1;
  ODEeqns =
   {
xsol'[tsol] == SolSpeed[xsol[tsol]/tsol, eta1, eta2, kappa],
x[t$initial] == x$initial
};
  NDSolve[ODEeqns, xsol, {tsol, t$left, t$right}]
  ]



SolPeakLeading[.25, 1, 2, -64, 1, 30]

NDSolve::ndode: The equations {True,0==SolSpeed[xsol[tsol]/tsol,0.25,1,2]} are not differential equations or initial conditions in the dependent variables {xsol}.
```
````

Comment: Wow, that’s a lot of code! It might be helpful for you (& others, too!) if you can formulate a minimum working example (MWE) that can be used to demonstrate the problem you’re having. As I see it, here, the issue is with your `SolSpeed` Function, as `xsol[tsol]/tsol` is still symbolic, and the function is calling for a numeric input, per the use of `?NumericQ`.

Comment: I know it's a ton of code, but I couldn't get a MWE that replicated the problem. When I exclude the ```sol``` function (largest chunk of the code) and just seed the initial conditions in ```SolPeakLeading```  it runs just fine with no complaints from ```NDSolve```.  But as soon as I implement the ```sol```  function I get the ```NDSolve``` error message trying to run my code.

Comment: So the issue is definitely with your `SolSpeed` function. You call for the first argument to satisfy `?NumericQ`, but in `SolPeakLanding` you are inserting an argument that is still symbolic, and you also call for multiple variables `x$val` and  `t$val` that are not included as arguments to the function `SolSpeed`. I would investigate these issues first.